# How to run Android app with Maven in Flutter?

Tags: maven, flutter

I have flutter project, there is android directory. And I want to use some libarary, but in order to reach this goal i have to use maven in android directory. Honestly i don't how to use maven, my task is create `pom.xml`, in which i can add dependcies. If anything [this link to library](https://github.com/fatsecret/fatsecret4j). How can i reach my goal?

Comment: Sorry I am failing to understand. The library link you mentioned has both gradle and maven dependency. By default you have gradle setup with flutter create. So just add the library dependency to the build.gradle file.

Comment: Follow the steps in the section `Add the following configuration to your build.gradle file`

Comment: elaborate your question

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation "[Integrate a Flutter module into your Android project](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup)" that you could follow.

In ["Add the Flutter module as a dependency"](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup#add-the-flutter-module-as-a-dependency), try to check ["Option A - Depend on the Android Archive (AAR)"](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup#option-a---depend-on-the-android-archive-aar)

> This option packages your Flutter library as a generic local Maven
> repository composed of AARs and POMs artifacts. This option allows
> your team to build the host app without installing the Flutter SDK.
> You can then distribute the artifacts from a local or remote
> repository.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the library you've shared, the library can also be added [using gradle](https://github.com/fatsecret/fatsecret4j#android-client-code). Simply add this config to your the build.gradle file located inside the Flutter project's `/android` folder.